# webAPI odata query: not filtering as I hoped

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am attempting to query my WebAPI thus:

```
http://localhost/api/channels?$expand=ScheduleMetadatas&$filter=ScheduleMetadatas/any(ScheduleMetadata: ScheduleMetadata/StartDateTime gt datetime'2013-12-06T00:00:00.00')
```

however the query is not filtering as expected, it simply returns all child ScheduleMetadata entities for each channel entity.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all channels, that had at least one Schedule metadata which is before a certain date. Form the channel that match it will return all schedules no matter the filter

Comment: is it possible to get what I want?

Comment: I think you should look at it the other way around. So doing a query on the schedule meta data. Or YouTube can add an extra parameter on the uri which filters the meta data.

Comment: Like :  public void Get([Fromuri]DateTime metadatadatefilter) {  return Context.Channel.Select(c => new Channel { Id = c.Id, Schedules = c.Schedules.Where(a => a.Date < metadatadatefilter), etc... }) }